# jQuery email form, how to send all info from the fields?

Tags: jquery, forms

I have a simple email contact form that and has multiple input fields. Right now, it only sends the value of one of the fields (message). How do I ammend the code so i can send all the info from the fields? I have about 15 fields.

Here is the code:

```
$('#submit').click(function(){

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "mail.php",
data: ({email : $("#email").val(), message: $("#message").val()}),
cache: false,
 error: function () {

    alert('did not go thru');
   },
success: function(html){
//$("#response").fadeIn("slow");
$("#tab1").html(html);
//setTimeout('$("#response").fadeOut("slow")',2000);
alert('mail sent');
}
});


 });
```

Answer (score 4):

If you give the form an id instead, and move the callback to the form's submit event, you can easily use the serialize method to automatically send the entire form:

```
$('#form-id').submit(function(){

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "mail.php",
data: $(this).serialize(),
cache: false,
 error: function () {

    alert('did not go thru');
   },
success: function(html){
//$("#response").fadeIn("slow");
$("#tab1").html(html);
//setTimeout('$("#response").fadeOut("slow")',2000);
alert('mail sent');
}
});


 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not adding the remaining fields to data?

Comment: yeah, i just tried that. it works. the only question that i now have is how do i add a break between the field values so they are not all together in the email?

Comment: All the field values will get posted to server side. It now depends on how you handle them there.

Comment: That would be something you'd do within mail.php.  the values you're passing are just like form fields, so format the email the same way you'd do with any form post.